# No package phpmyadmin available. Error nothing to do

Tags: centos, phpmyadmin

Im using system Centos 7 Now in my VPS I have configure correct LAMP and directadmin.

Php, apache web server etc working correct. I have issue with phpmyadmin. I see  phpmyadmin is not available in build in repo centos and require install EPEL.

So I do it:

```
[root@~]# yum install epel-release -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.fi.muni.cz
 * epel: mirror.vpsnet.com
 * extras: ftp.fi.muni.cz
 * updates: ftp.fi.muni.cz
Package epel-release-7-14.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Now I again try install phpmyadmin:

```
[root@ ~]# sudo yum -y install phpmyadmin
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.fi.muni.cz
 * epel: mirror.vpsnet.com
 * extras: ftp.fi.muni.cz
 * updates: ftp.fi.muni.cz
No package phpmyadmin available.
```

Still the same issue. Any solution?

I try this:

```
[root@ ~]# cd /usr/local/directadmin/custombuild
[root@ custombuild]# ./build phpmyadmin
Downloading             webapps.logrotate...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Downloading             phpMyAdmin-5.1.3-all-languages.tar.gz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Adding AuthLog to /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin-5.1.3-all-languages/config.inc.php
Adding PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning to /var/www/html/phpMyAdmin-5.1.3-all-languages/config.inc.php
phpMyAdmin 5.1.3-all-languages installation is done.
[root@custombuild]#
```

Now is installed but when I access to my_ip/phpmyadmin then still not found. Anysolution?